# Is it possible to label certain histogram values/members using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot geom_density_ridges and geom_segment functions, I am able to building a series of histograms (subset of the ridges function) that analyze a population of values for each month (of the last 15 months, rolling).

Here is the code:

```
ggplot(queryResults_cleaned, aes(x =DAYS_TO_FA, y = fct_rev(DATE_TEXT))) +
  geom_density_ridges(stat="binline", bins = 75, scale = 0.95, draw_baseline = FALSE) +
  labs(title = 'Monthly Plots of Time to First Action', y='Month Received', x = 'Days to First Review Action') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,130,5)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=50, xend = 50, y=1,yend=months_2019), 
             linetype = "dashed", size = 1.5,
             color = "black") +
  geom_segment(aes(x=75, xend = 75, y=months_2019,yend=(months_2018+months_2019 + 1)), 
             linetype = "dashed", size = 1.5,
             color = "black") + 
  geom_segment(data = segment_data_kept, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend),
             linetype = "dotted", size = 1.5,
             color = "red")
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Is there a way to force ggplot to label all values above a certain cutoff with some part of the dataframe (queryResults_cleaned) that is used?

Comment: Please kindly make this question reproducible. A very possible reason why this question was ignored when asked the first time - it's difficult to reproduce. It contains most likely too much unnecessary code. And the desired output is not exactly clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add labels to a ggplot, we can use either the `geom_tex` or `geom_label` function. First, I create your base ggplot with monthly histogram. I'll ignore the segments since you have already managed to do that for yourself. I'm using my own simulated dataset called `df_cleaned`, which should have a similar structure to your dataset called `queryResults_cleaned`. The code to generate this data is given at the end.

---

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)   # Needed for 'fct_rev' function
library(ggridges)  # Needed for 'geom_density_ridges' function

p <- ggplot(df_cleaned, aes(x = DAYS_TO_FA, y = fct_rev(DATE_TEXT))) +
  geom_density_ridges(stat="binline", bins = 75, 
                      scale = 0.95, 
                      draw_baseline = FALSE) +
  labs(title = 'Monthly Plots of Time to First Action', 
       y='Month Received', 
       x = 'Days to First Review Action') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,130,5))
```

---

You should get your base ggplot without the segments.

Next, define the cut-off values for each year (change accordingly).

```
cut_off_2018 <- 115
cut_off_2019 <- 80
```

Then, filter your dataset using these cut-off values.

```
LABELS <- df_cleaned %>%
  filter(DAYS_TO_FA > cut_off_2018 & format(DATE, "%Y")==2018 | 
         DAYS_TO_FA > cut_off_2019 & format(DATE, "%Y")==2019)
```

Finally, use `geom_text` or `geom_label` to add the labels.

```
p + geom_text(data=LABELS, 
              aes(x=DAYS_TO_FA, y=DATE_TEXT, 
                  col=format(DATE, "%Y"),
                  label=DAYS_TO_FA),
              nudge_y = -0.2,       # shift label down a bit
              check_overlap = TRUE,
              show.legend = FALSE,
              size = 3) +
  #           label="<label>", # to manually add a global label to all
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","green4"))
```

---

[image]

---

**Data** - simulated since no data provide in question:

Generate the range of dates to sample from:

```
dates1 <- as.Date(c("2018-04-01", "2018-12-31"))
dates2 <- as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-09-30"))
DATES1 <- seq.Date(dates1[1], dates1[2], 1)
DATES2 <- seq.Date(dates2[1], dates2[2], 1)
```

Assume a sample size of 500 (per year) and set a random number seed so others can reproduce the graph.

```
N <- 500
set.seed(123)
```

Create the data, separately for the two years since they look like they come from two different populations.

```
df1 <- data.frame(DAYS_TO_FA=round(rchisq(n=N, df=75, ncp=1)),
                 DATE=sample(DATES1, size=N, replace=TRUE))
df2 <- data.frame(DAYS_TO_FA=round(rchisq(n=N, df=50, ncp=1)),
                  DATE=sample(DATES2, size=N, replace=TRUE))
```

Combine them into one data set.

```
df <- rbind(df1, df2)

library(dplyr)
df_cleaned <- mutate(df, DATE_TEXT=format(DATE, format="%Y-%m"))

str(df_cleaned)
# 'data.frame': 1000 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ DAYS_TO_FA: num  84 79 73 92 69 81 77 97 76 65 ...
# $ DATE      : Date, format: "2018-10-09" ...
# $ DATE_TEXT : chr  "2018-10" "2018-04" "2018-05" "2018-05" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way to accomplish this is to create a new field in your data indicating whether the value is above your desired cutoff. You can do this the `dplyr` way by piping the data through a `mutate` step and then into `ggplot`, while adding a `geom_text()` for your new label at the end. Note that you will have to define "Some_Cut" in the creation of "MyLabels".

```
queryResults_cleaned %>% 
  mutate(MyLabels = case_when(DAYS_TO_FA >= Some_Cut ~ as.character(DAYS_TO_FA), TRUE ~ '')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x =DAYS_TO_FA, y = fct_rev(DATE_TEXT))) + 
  geom_density_ridges(stat="binline", bins = 75, scale = 0.95, draw_baseline = FALSE) +
  labs(title = 'Monthly Plots of Time to First Action', y='Month Received', x = 'Days to First Review Action') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,130,5)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=50, xend = 50, y=1,yend=months_2019), 
               linetype = "dashed", size = 1.5,
               color = "black") +
  geom_segment(aes(x=75, xend = 75, y=months_2019,yend=(months_2018+months_2019 + 1)), 
               linetype = "dashed", size = 1.5,
               color = "black") + 
  geom_segment(data = segment_data_kept, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend),
               linetype = "dotted", size = 1.5,
               color = "red") +
  geom_text(aes(label = MyLabels))
```